# Create object of conditional type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I'm trying to run alternate code depending on a conditional type. However, it looks like it's not possible to do that in TypeScript. Here's my attempt:

```
class alt_a {
        what(): string {
                return "alt_a";
        }
}

class alt_b {
        what(): string {
                return "alt_b";
        }
}

// OK
let a: alt_a = new alt_a;
console.log(a.what());
let b: alt_b = new alt_b;
console.log(b.what());

// Doesn't work
type cond<T> = T extends true ? alt_a : alt_b;
let c: cond<true> = new cond<true>;
console.log(c.what());
```

When trying to compile (tsc --version == "Version 3.3.3333"), I get the following:

`(30,35): error TS1005: '(' expected.`

Is there a way to do something of the kind in TypeScript? Even better would be a way to access static members of alternate classes, just like "constexpr" members in C++.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with types like that, but you can easily create a factory function that returns a contructor based on a condition, and then `new` it

Comment: @ritaj: that would be nice. How is it done (I'm quite new to TS)?

Answer (score 0):

```
class alt_a {
    what(): string {
        return "alt_a";
    }
}

class alt_b {
    what(): string {
        return "alt_b";
    }
}

function getConstructor(condition: boolean) {
    return condition ? alt_a : alt_b;
}

const constructor = getConstructor(true);

const c = new constructor();
c.what();
```

Comment: This doesn't depend on a type.

Comment: I literally said you can't do it with types

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make any decision in your javascript code based on typescript types.  The typescript types are completely removed when the code is compiled to javascript.

`cond<T>` is just a type.  You cannot use it as a class constructor.  You must also define the javascript behavior and choose the correct class based on a javascript variable.

```
type cond<T> = T extends true ? alt_a : alt_b;

const createCond = <T extends boolean>(bool: T): cond<T> => {
    // the choice is made based on the variable, not the type
    const selected = bool ? alt_a : alt_b;
    // have to assert when using a conditional as a return type
    return new selected() as cond<T>; 
}

const a = createCond(true); // type: alt_a
const b = createCond(false); // type: alt_b
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/rw2dxm)

Comment: cond<T> resolves "statically" either to "alt_a" or "alt_b", depending on a condition that is known at compile time. So one would expect that the expression "cond<true>" or "cond<false>" should be substituted with the actual type. I guess metaprogramming is not possible, then.